# What is the meaning of enforce parameter in AngularJS Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I was going through the details of how angular actually creates factory just by using module.factory() method.

I found that internally angular uses following method which internally uses provider only

```
function factory(name, factoryFn, enforce)
```

So my question is regarding the third parameter `enforce` of this function ,what it actually does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an Angular service or factory, behind the scenes, Angular eventually uses the same function for both:

```
function factory(name, factoryFn, enforce) {
  return provider(name, {
    $get: enforce !== false ? enforceReturnValue(name, factoryFn) : factoryFn
  });
}
```

When creating a service, a return value is generally not sent, and behind the scenes, `Object.create()` is called to create an object containing the `sayHello` method.

```
app.service('MyService', function () {
  this.sayHello = function () {
    console.log('hello');
  };
});
```

However, when creating a factory, an object literal is returned:

```
app.factory('MyService', function () {
  return {
    sayHello: function () {
      console.log('hello');
    };
  }
});
```

Basically, enforce is used to enforce a return value. It's not just a question of "Is this a service or factory?" since you can still return an object literal from a service if you wanted to:

```
app.service('MyService', function () {
  return {
    sayHello: function () {
      console.log('hello');
    };
  }
});
```

Regarding the question: "Which should you use?" check out this:

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html